What's the grammatical function of the first part of the sentence below?
A regular fixture since the Barcelona 1992 Olympics, badminton now has five disciplines at the Games after mixed doubles was introduced at Atlanta 1996.

Badminton, a regular fixture since the Barcelona 1992 Olympics, etc.
OR
A regular fixture since the Barcelona 1992 Olympics, badminton etc.
That is called an apposition.
Here is a much easier one:
Example: Our pediatrician, André Wilson, was born in California.
Explanation: Our pediatrician is still a relatively precise identifier so André Wilson is not considered essential.
An appositive clarifies something already mentioned. They are usually nouns or noun phrases, but can also be verb phrases.

An appositive is a word or phrase that refers to the same thing as
another noun in the same sentence. It is placed beside another noun or
pronoun to explain or identify it.
Applying commas correctly with an appositive can be tricky. A comma is
needed for clarifying information that is not essential to
understanding the noun, and commas are not needed if the clarifying
information is essential.

commas and appositives
Going to Dallas, travelling there, was not easy for those employees.

That is a noun phrase. It is headed by the noun "fixture". It introduces the context of the clause that follows it.

A noun phrase is not a function. It's a part of speech.

A noun phrase is not a function nor a part of speech.  It's a type of phrase.


Types of phrases were created to make it more convenient to work with parts of speech. It's impossible to consider them outside the scope of parts of speech. To me, it's more comfortable to consider the phrases as an extension for parts of speech rather than a separate grammatical set. 2) The noun phrase discussed functions perhaps as a supplement, but I'm not sure.


If we remove "a regular fixture since the Barcelona 1992 Olympics", we get "badminton now has five disciplines at the Games after mixed doubles was introduced at Atlanta 1996". The word "now" confuses me. Maybe the noun phrase removed was the modifier of "now"?

"Now" is just an adverb meaning "at the present time".  It is used to make a contrast with the past in this case.  "At the present time badminton has 5 disciplines (which is more than it had in past)."
